# Setting Timeout Parameter in httpd file

Tags: apache

I am trying to change the timeout parameter in apache 2.4.Please can someone help me with changing it, since  the term TimeOut itself is missing in my httpd.conf file which is quite surprising. But  I can see that my session  expires in 60s.

Please advise me on what modules are required to be changed in the httpd file.

-vijay

Comment: Not sure what kind of timeout you want to set: The period after which a browser aborts a pending request to your Apache? Note that Apache itself has no notion of a session.

Answer (score 1):

set these in php.ini:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1500
session.cache_expire = 1700
```

and sure that don't set session lifetime to another value in anywhere in your code.
for more details view this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: I am using PERL CGI. Is there a similar setting available for PERL as well?